# Proper variable name for find method

Tags: javascript, variables, find

I'm Japanese web developer. I'm currently thinking about the proper variable name for the result from javascript find method. I would rather not use "result" because it is too simple and it's hard to understand what's inside. Does anyone have any idea?

```js
const targetChar = 'someName1';

let arrayOfObj = [
  {
    name: 'someName1',
    age: 38
  },
  {
    name: 'someName2',
    age: 24
  }
];

const result = arrayOfObj.find((obj) => {
  return obj.name === targetChar;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "proper variable name". Go with what makes sense to you

Comment: It looks to be an array of people, so perhaps the array should be `people` (not `arrayOfObj`), or something similar - be precise. An individual item in such an array might be `person`, but again - be precise. Are these any particular sorts of people? Eg, if they were students, the array could be named `students` and the find result `student` or `foundStudent`

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! I'm gonna change `arrayOfObj` to more precise name.  For Japanese, sometimes it is soo hard to name variables...lol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any name that is in unicode is proper name so don't worry. Maybe you can check out commonly used naming conventions for commonly used javascript libraries or go with `foundPeople`. But if you are going to use it for an if statement you can choose `isFound` or `hasFound` which is shorter and easier to read.

The context, in other words where you are going to use the variable is important when choosing names. If the variable is global, or if you are going to use the found item later, a more descriptive name could be more helpful but if you are merely checking if such a person exist, shorter ones like `isFound`, `hasFound` or `isExist` is better.

Comment: I'm gonna go with `foundNames`. Thank you so much for your advice! It helps me a lot!

Comment: Glad to be helpful.